# How do I find compare and return an element within a map function for each iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a quiz app.

I would like to have the users' answer displayed on the results page of the quiz underneath each question.

So far I have mapped over all of the `questions` from the original data source along with all the `correctAnswers` and these are being displayed.

Now within the same `.map` I would like to also display (under each question) the 
`userAnswer` which  holds the data for the answer the user selected.

I thought that if I was in a `.map`, on each iteration I could go into the `answers` array within each iteration of the source data and `.find` which of those answers then matched the answer the user selected, if that makes sense?

At the moment the expected behaviour only works for the last question.  i.e i see the correct answer and user answer for the last question.

Please see code below:

```
const ResultCard = ({ score, getQuestions, qbank, userAnswer }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>You scored {score} out of 5! </div>

      <div className="playBtnBox">
        <button className="playBtn" type="button" onClick={getQuestions}>
          Play again
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        {qbank.map((questionObject, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="questionBox"> {questionObject.question}</div>
              <div className="resultCardCorrect">
                Correct Answer: {questionObject.correct}
              </div>
              <div className="resultCardCorrect">
               User Answer:
                {questionObject.answers.find(answer => answer === userAnswer)}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Source data that I am mapping over:

```
const qBank = [
  {
    question:
      "Virgin Trains, Virgin Atlantic and Virgin Racing, are all companies owned by which famous entrepreneur?   ",
    answers: ["Richard Branson", "Alan Sugar", "Donald Trump", "Bill Gates"],
    correct: "Richard Branson",
    questionId: "099099"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Where is the train station "Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch"?',
    answers: ["Wales", "Moldova", "Czech Republic", "Denmark"],
    correct: "Wales",
    questionId: "183452"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which company did Valve cooperate with in the creation of the Vive?",
    answers: ["HTC", "Oculus", "Google", "Razer"],
    correct: "HTC",
    questionId: "267908"
  },
  {
    question: "What's the name of Batman's  parents?",
    answers: [
      "Thomas & Martha",
      "Joey & Jackie",
      "Jason & Sarah",
      "TodWhat is the most common surd & Mira"
    ],
    correct: "Thomas & Martha",
    questionId: "333247"
  },
  {
    question: "name Wales?",
    answers: ["Jones", "Williams", "Davies", "Evans"],
    correct: "Jones",
    questionId: "496293"
  },
  {
    question:
      "What was the name of the WWF professional wrestling tag team made up of the wrestlers Ax and Smash?",
    answers: [
      "Demolition",
      "The Dream Team",
      "The Bushwhackers",
      "The British Bulldogs"
    ],
    correct: "Demolition",
    questionId: "588909"
  }
]

];
```

This is where the userAnswer comes from `QuestionBox.js` component:

```
const QuestionBox = ({
  question,
  options,
  correct,
  incrementScore,
  incrementResponse,
  userAnswer
}) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(""); // text to display whether user response is correct or not initially is nothing.
  const [answers, setAnswerFunction] = useState(options); // the answers to each question from the api

  const computeAnswer = (answer, index) => {
    if (answer === correct) {
      setResponse("correct");
      incrementScore();
      incrementResponse();
      userAnswer(answer);
    } else {
      setResponse("sorry wrong!");
      incrementResponse();
      userAnswer(answer);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <div className="question"> {question} </div>
      {answers.map((answer, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={index}
            className="answerBtn"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setAnswerFunction([answer]); // sends the answer clicked by the user to the state
              computeAnswer(answer); // sends the answer the user clicks to the computeAnswer function and sets the response to correct or wrong.
            }}
          >
            {answer}
          </button>
        );
      })}
      {response === "correct" ? (
        <div className="correctResponse"> {response} </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="wrongResponse"> {response} </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default QuestionBox;
```

And how it is added to the state in the top level componenet which houses the `ResultsCard.js`

```
userAnswer = answer => {                                                             
  this.setState({ userAnswer: answer }, () => {                                      
    console.log(this.state.userAnswer);                                                                                                                            
  });                                                                                
};
```

Comment: So, in `userAnswer` variable what are you passing? just the last question correct answer? or an array of all answers given by user?

Comment: can you add the userAnswer prop

Comment: Check this one @Angela, https://codesandbox.io/s/61799766-so-bx65x. Will improve it it required. since the userAnswer prop was not added. Will add it as answer if it worked for you

Comment: @palaѕн i'm passing the answer the user selected from the 4 possible answers  as a string i.e " Joey & Jackie" .

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS add it where? When I do add it on it's own in a separate `div` at the bottom of the file it just prints the answer the user chose for the last question :S

Comment: But how do we know that answer is for which questions inside `ResultCard` component?

Comment: @AngelaInniss Add it as the answer for the question, then can you provide the props what you are passing in userAnswer. I think if you doesn't give the info we won't be able to help on further

Comment: I have updated the code showing where the `userAnswer` comes from. It may be a messy way to do it please advise, and let me know if it makes sense to you @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: how does you question application works, is it like at last once the user submits only u will be showing or clicking on each question answer option and confirm you are showing the answer, i think the above is fine but there can be a better way. If you can explain more on the above, also did you checked the codesandbox that i have shared

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS basically on the `QuestionBox` component the user clicks a button and it updates the state `answers` and only the button that the user selected appears on the screen. Within the `onClick` the users answer `answer` also gets sent to a function called `userAnswer` which is on the component above which sets the state in that component. The state is then passed down to the `ResultsCard` which is where I want to display each `userAnswer` for each question. I   `console.log(this.state.userAnswer)` & appears in the console but i cant get each one to display on the `ResultsCard.js` file.

Comment: yes i did see your sandbox thank you it makes sense the way you have done it but there are so many questions and i dont want to add an `id` for all the `userAnswers`

Comment: can you create a codesandbox so it will be easy to figure it out, usually the id will be the linking part of the questions array and the answers that user has submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213875/discussion-between-angela-inniss-and-dileep-thomas).